# How to satisfy the OFL and OFL RFN clause?

Tags: font, ofl

A font designer that is hosting font on Google fonts has released a latest font version which does not fit with my design. I rather use the previous version of the font and self host it. So I have generated the font-face kit via https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and renamed the font  to ;

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myfontname';
    src: url('myfontname.woff2') format('woff2'), url('myfontname.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Now since I have changed the font metrics `within the file` by OFL I need to change the font name as well.

This is the part that confuses me. I want to leave all the credits and copyright of the original font designer but becuase I am forced to change the font name do I have to change the copyright, designer website and credits also?

The font will be packaged with WordPress theme so the OFL redistribution clause should be satisfied with that but the renaming part is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [OFL FAQ](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=OFL-FAQ_web#a8c83d32) -

> Question: 3.1 Can I change the fonts? Are there any limitations to what things I can and cannot change?
>
> Answer: You are allowed to change anything, as long as such changes do not violate the terms of the license. In other words, you are not allowed to remove the copyright statement(s) from the font, but you could put additional information into it that covers your contribution. See the placeholders in the OFL header template for recommendations on where to add your own statements.

Which means you should add your details to the existing copyright details.

You should never expect a license to allow you to remove any copyright notice, it will always be a case of adding your copyright for your portion of the work.